# Why use numerical methods for solving ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I hope this is not considered an 'opinion' question. I'm currently studying numerical methods for solving ODEs. The theory relies on the problem being well-posed, and uses Picard-Lindelof to conclude that Lipschitz continuity is sufficient for this. But then...why not just use Picard iteration to get the exact solution? There quite many symbolic based programs (like for example Wolfram) that would be suitable for this, no?

Comment: Only a (very) small fraction of ODEs can be explicitly solved.

Comment: @Rigel why can't they all be solved using Picard iteration?

Comment: Just try it out. Solve $y'(x)=\cos(y(x))$ via Picard iteration with symbolic integration. Or try the pendulum equation $y''(x)=-\sin(y(x))$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann all right, will do!